# Date Returning NaN In Mozilla and IE With Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, internet-explorer, mozilla

Currently, I have been testing out my time function in different browsers. I am simply grabbing a MySql Timestamp and converting it to Unix Time, problem is that is not working in Mozilla or Internet Explorer!

The problem is I think when I call this line of code:

```
var unixtime = new Date(timestamp).getTime() / 1000;
```

And `timestamp` would be something like: `2015-07-28 08:55:53` (for example).

All other lines that I call seem to work perfectly fine, and again, this is working in Chrome. So why would this code not be working in Mozilla and IE?

Here is my full code:

```
function addS(value) {
    if (value == 1) {
        var string = "";
    }
    else {
        var string = "s";
    }
    return string;
}

function timeago(timestamp) {
    var unixtime = new Date(timestamp).getTime() / 1000;
    var unixtimenow = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    var timediff = unixtimenow - unixtime;
    var timediffmins = Math.round(timediff / 60);
    var timediffhours = Math.round(timediffmins / 60);
    var timediffdays = Math.round(timediffhours / 24);
    var timediffweeks = Math.round(timediffdays / 7);
    var timediffmonths = Math.round(timediffweeks / 4);
    var timediffyears = Math.round(timediffmonths / 12);

    var value = null;

    if (timediff < 60) {
        value = "a moment";
    }
    else if (timediffmins < 60) {
        value = timediffmins + " minute" + addS(timediffmins);
    }
    else if (timediffhours < 24) {
        value = timediffhours + " hour" + addS(timediffhours);
    }
    else if (timediffdays < 7) {
        value = timediffdays + " day" + addS(timediffdays);
    }
    else if (timediffweeks < 4) {
        value = timediffweeks + " week" + addS(timediffweeks);
    }
    else if (timediffmonths < 12) {
        value = timediffmonths + " month" + addS(timediffmonths);
    }
    else {
        value = timediffyears + " year" + addS(timediffyears);
    }
    return value;
}

timeago(data[k]["datecreated"]) + " ago";
```

---

So simply, my question is, why is this not working in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on MDN:

> new Date(dateString);
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

From [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) on MDN:

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may
>   be used, **but results may be unexpected**).

(Bold is mine)

Example of RFC2822 formatted date:

```
Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT
```

Example of ISO formats:

```
2011-10-10
```

```
2011-10-10T14:48:00
```

Your date is not in one of these two formats so browser behaviour is undefined.

Try formatting your string as per standard, or parsing it and using the constructor:

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will test it and then let you know :)

Comment: works perfectly! :) Thank you, if you are curious, here is the code I used `var t = timestamp.split(/[- :]/);
  var unixtime = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]) / 1000;`.